# How to hide the hyperlink underline and maintain the origin font color in javascripts?

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink

How to hide the hyperlink underline and maintain the origin by avoid change to blue color font in JavaScript. My JavaScript code :

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('selectprofiletype.php','Crm.com - Create',
'width=700,height=350' ) ">&nbsp;&nbsp;User Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why javascript? Use the CSS.

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps:

```
a {
    color: #0060B6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover 
{
     text-decoration:none; 
     color: #0060B6;
     cursor:pointer;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems more like a `css` question

```
a{
text-decoration: none; 
color: your colour here;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change the JavaScript to the following (and use any of the other answers for the CSS instead of using an inline style)

```
<a href="selectprofiletype.php" target="crm_create" style="text-decoration:none"
onclick="var w = window.open(this.href,this.target,'width=700,height=350');
  return w?false:true;">&nbsp;&nbsp;User Profile</a>
```

since your code will give problems in several browser - for example the window name may not have spaces

The code would be nicer if unobtrusive:

```
window.onload=function() {
 document.getElementById("crm").onclick=function() {
  var w = window.open(this.href,this.target,'width=700,height=350');
  return w?false:true;
 }
}
```

using just

```
<a id="crm" href="selectprofiletype.php" target="crm_create">User Profile</a>
```